# If/else statement checking opacity, and adding class but not removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The below function checks the opacity of the header (which fades out on scroll) and if it is less than 1 turns off pointer-events(clickability) by adding the class headerclickoff. For some reason it wont remove it! Any idea what's wrong with my code?

```
function headerclickoff(){
  var opacity = $("header").css("opacity");
if ( opacity <= 1) {
    console.log("working");
  $("header").addClass("headerclickoff");
} else {
  $("header").removeClass("headerclickoff");
};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Values) values varies from [0...1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Values) so your condition will always be true.

So I think you need to add the class if opacity is less than 1, not less than or equal to

```
function headerclickoff() {
    var opacity = $("header").css("opacity");
    if (opacity < 1) {
        console.log("working");
        $("header").addClass("headerclickoff");
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("headerclickoff");
    }
}
```

---

You can also use toggleClass

```
function headerclickoff() {
    var opacity = $("header").css("opacity");
    console.log('opacity', opacity);
    $("header").toggleClass("headerclickoff", opacity < 1);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erotuch8/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Just tried it with no luck. The class is not being added now. Strange.As an alternative I removed all clickable items from the header and layered them using z-index, and turned off all pointer-events for header directly in the stylesheet. I really wish I knew what was wrong though. Thanks for yout help!

Comment: @sjos can you try to recreate your case in the attached fiddle and share the updated fiddle